# Visualizing the number of pieces attacking each square

Tags: software, chessboards, visualization

Are there any software programs or tools available that can display the number of pieces attacking each square?

Answer (score 3):

This python script will show how many white/black attackers on every square.

It will also generate an image in `png` format where the attacked square is marked with `X` and the attacker locations are colored green.

Edit: Added code to generate an attack heatmap.
Edit: Update attack heatmap board labels.

### Code

```
"""
pip install chess
pip install cairosvg
"""

import chess
import chess.svg
from cairosvg import svg2png


def main():
    fen = 'rn1r3k/pp2qpp1/1bb1p3/6p1/2BP4/P4N2/1PQ1RPPP/4R1K1 w - - 0 19'

    board = chess.Board(fen)
    print(board)
    print()

    for square in range(64):
        sq_name = chess.square_name(square)
        w_attackers = board.attackers(chess.WHITE, square)
        b_attackers = board.attackers(chess.BLACK, square)

        svg = chess.svg.board(
            board,
            fill=dict.fromkeys((w_attackers | b_attackers), "#00FF00"),
            squares=(chess.SquareSet([square])),
            size=350,
        )

        png_fn = f'{sq_name}_board.png'
        svg2png(bytestring=svg, write_to=png_fn)

        print(f'sq: {sq_name}, wattackers: {len(list(w_attackers))}, battackers: {len(list(b_attackers))}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Sample Image Output

a4_board.png

[image]

---

e6_board.png

[image]

---

### Sample Text Output

```
r n . r . . . k
p p . . q p p .
. b b . p . . .
. . . . . . p .
. . B P . . . .
P . . . . N . .
. P Q . R P P P
. . . . R . K .

sq: a1, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: b1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: c1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: d1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: e1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: f1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: g1, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: h1, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: a2, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: b2, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: c2, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: d2, wattackers: 3, battackers: 0
sq: e2, wattackers: 3, battackers: 0
sq: f2, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: g2, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: h2, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: a3, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: b3, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: c3, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: d3, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: e3, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: f3, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: g3, wattackers: 2, battackers: 0
sq: h3, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: a4, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: b4, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: c4, wattackers: 1, battackers: 0
sq: d4, wattackers: 1, battackers: 2
sq: e4, wattackers: 2, battackers: 1
sq: f4, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: g4, wattackers: 0, battackers: 0
sq: h4, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: a5, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: b5, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: c5, wattackers: 1, battackers: 2
sq: d5, wattackers: 1, battackers: 3
sq: e5, wattackers: 3, battackers: 0
sq: f5, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: g5, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: h5, wattackers: 0, battackers: 0
sq: a6, wattackers: 1, battackers: 2
sq: b6, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: c6, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: d6, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: e6, wattackers: 2, battackers: 2
sq: f6, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: g6, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: h6, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: a7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: b7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: c7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: d7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 4
sq: e7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 0
sq: f7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: g7, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: h7, wattackers: 1, battackers: 1
sq: a8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 0
sq: b8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: c8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
sq: d8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: e8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 3
sq: f8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: g8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 2
sq: h8, wattackers: 0, battackers: 1
```

You have to change the FEN in the code for other positions.

### Updated code to generate an attack heatmap

The map is saved in html file.

```
"""
pip install chess
pip install cairosvg
pip install numpy
pip install plotly
"""

import chess
import chess.svg
from cairosvg import svg2png
import plotly.express as px
import numpy


def main():
    fen = 'rn1r3k/pp2qpp1/1bb1p3/6p1/2BP4/P4N2/1PQ1RPPP/4R1K1 w - - 0 19'

    board = chess.Board(fen)
    print(board)
    print()

    att = {i: 0 for i in range(64)}

    for square in range(64):
        sq_name = chess.square_name(square)
        w_attackers = board.attackers(chess.WHITE, square)
        b_attackers = board.attackers(chess.BLACK, square)

        att[square] += len(w_attackers) + len(b_attackers)

        svg = chess.svg.board(
            board,
            fill=dict.fromkeys((w_attackers | b_attackers), "#00FF00"),
            squares=(chess.SquareSet([square])),
            size=350,
        )

        png_fn = f'{sq_name}_board.png'
        svg2png(bytestring=svg, write_to=png_fn)

        print(f'sq: {sq_name}, wattackers: {len(list(w_attackers))}, battackers: {len(list(b_attackers))}')

    # Create a heatmap using plotly.
    att_list = []
    for k, v in att.items():
        att_list.append(v)

    np_arr = numpy.array(att_list)
    np_arr_8_by_8 = np_arr.reshape(8, 8)
    np_arr_8_by_8_flip = numpy.flip(np_arr_8_by_8, 0)

    fig = px.imshow(np_arr_8_by_8_flip, text_auto=True,
                labels=dict(color='numattacks'),
                x=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
                y=['8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'])
    fig.write_html('attack_heatmap.html')
    # fig.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

[image]